# Pythonic iterable difference

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written some code to find all the items that are in one iterable and not another and vice versa.  I was originally using the built in set difference, but the computation was rather slow as there were millions of items being stored in each set.  Since I know there will be at most a few thousand differences I wrote the below version:

```
def differences(a_iter, b_iter):
    a_items, b_items = set(), set()

    def remove_or_add_if_none(a_item, b_item, a_set, b_set):
        if a_item is None:
            if b_item in a_set:
                a_set.remove(b_item)
            else:
                b_set.add(b)

    def remove_or_add(a_item, b_item, a_set, b_set):
        if a in b_set:
            b_set.remove(a)
            if b in a_set:
                a_set.remove(b)
            else:
                b_set.add(b)
            return True
        return False

    for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(a_iter, b_iter):
        if a is None or b is None:
            remove_or_add_if_none(a, b, a_items, b_items)
            remove_or_add_if_none(b, a, b_items, a_items)
            continue

        if a != b:
            if remove_or_add(a, b, a_items, b_items) or \
               remove_or_add(b, a, b_items, a_items):
                continue
            a_items.add(a)
            b_items.add(b)

    return a_items, b_items
```

However, the above code doesn't seem very pythonic so I'm looking for alternatives or suggestions for improvement.

Comment: How much faster is yours than the built-in set difference?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more pythonic solution:

```
a, b = set(a_iter), set(b_iter)

return a - b, b - a
```

Pythonic does not mean fast, but rather elegant and readable.

Here is a solution that might be faster:

```
a, b = set(a_iter), set(b_iter)

# Get all the candidate return values
symdif = a.symmetric_difference(b)

# Since symdif has much fewer elements, these might be faster
return symdif - b, symdif - a
```

Now, about writing custom “fast” algorithms in Python instead of using the built-in operations: it's a very bad idea.

The set operators are heavily optimized, and written in C, which is generally much, much faster than Python. 
You could write an algorithm in C (or Cython), but then keep in mind that Python's set algorithms were written and optimized by world-class geniuses.
Unless you're extremely good at optimization, it's probably not worth the effort. On the other hand, if you do manage to speed things up substantially, please share your code; I bet it'd have a chance of getting into Python itself.

For a more realistic approach, try eliminating calls to Python code. For instance, if your objects have a custom equality operator, figure out a way to remove it.

But don't get your hopes up. Working with millions of pieces of data will always take a long time. I don't know where you're using this, but maybe it's better to make the computer busy for a minute than to spend the time optimizing set algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

i think your code is broken - try it with `[1,1]` and `[1,2]` and you'll get that `1` is in one set but not the other.

```
> print differences([1,1],[1,2])                                                   
(set([1]), set([2]))
```

you can trace this back to the effect of the `if a != b` test (which is assuming something about ordering that is not present in simple set differences).

without that test, which probably discards many values, i don't think your method is going to be any faster than built-in sets.  the argument goes something like: you really do need to create one set in memory to hold all the data (your bug came from not doing that).  a naive set approach creates two sets.  so the best you can do is save half the time, and you also have to do the work, in python, of what is probably efficient c code.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought python set operations would be the best performance you could get out of the standard library.

Perhaps it's the particular implementation you chose that's the problem, rather than the data structures and attendant operations themselves. Here's an alternate implementation that should be give you better performance.

For sequence comparison tasks in which the sequences are large, avoid, if at all possible, putting the objects that comprise the sequences into the containers used for the comparison--better to work with indices instead. If the objects in your sequences are unordered, then sort them.

So for instance, i use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/), the numerical python library, for these sort of tasks:

```
# a, b are 'fake' index arrays of type boolean
import numpy as NP
a, b  = NP.random.randint(0, 2, 10), NP.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
a, b = NP.array(a, dtype=bool), NP.array(b, dtype=bool)

# items a and b have in common:
NP.sum(NP.logical_and(a, b))

# the converse (the differences)
NP.sum(NP.logical_or(a, b))
```